# nginx: worker_proccesses directive doesn't work

Tags: nginx

I wanted to try to set the worker processes in nginx, but it throws me this error:

> nginx: [emerg] "worker_processes" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1
>   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

here is my code

```
worker_processes 4;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
worker_priority 0;
worker_cpu_affinity
0001 0010 0100 1000;

server {
    server_name --.--.--.---;
    listen 80;


    #root /var/www/devsites/wordpress/;
    root /var/www/devsites/trademob/tm-hp-v2/;
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Which error message ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You said that your error message was:

```
nginx: [emerg] "worker_processes" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Place this directive at the top of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` instead of in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`. The [`worker_processes`](http://nginx.org/r/worker_processes) directive is valid only at the top level of the configuration.

The same applies to all the other `worker_*` directives you've used.

Comment: Thanks! after 2 painful days of figuring out, this solved the issue!

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your configuration file:

```
worker_rlimit_
nofile 8192;
```

It appears that this line got split by accident. It should appear as:

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
```

The same error seems to have happened with the line beginning with `worker_cpu_affinity`.

Once you fix this, you should get your server back up and running.

Comment: I have fixed this syntax error, but it doesnt work